# Rails nested comments without using gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, tree

I am building a simple blog and I do like to implement reddit-like nested replies. So far I have Posts and Comments.

I have tried to look for guide or examples but all of the examples are either using gems or are outdated. Can you suggest me how to approach the problem ?

I started with editing routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
   resources :comments
end
```

Comment model:

```
 has_many :comments
```

I am not sure how to modify the create function in the controller and how to extend the comments/_form.html

And what are the remaining steps ?

Answer (score 0):

This is doable via a[ccepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for). Check out the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) on complex forms to get an idea of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I can refer you to a good [article](https://github.com/pluralsight/guides/blob/master/published/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes/article.md) on this subject.
Well, if you need to ask any questions after reading, just leave a comment.